# Cumulative Distribution Function of $X = Y*I + Z*(1-I)$

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have a random variable $X = Y*I + Z*(1-I)$ where $Y~N(u, sigma^2)\,,\,\, Z~N(u, sigmac^2)$, and $I~B(1,1-p)$.

What I can't seem to figure out is how to get a cumulative distribution function for $X$. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
  \Pr \left[ X \leqslant x \right] & = & \left( 1 - p \right) \Pr \left[ Y
  \leqslant x \right] + p \Pr \left[ Z \leqslant x \right]\\
  & = & \left( 1 - p \right) \Phi \left( \frac{x - u}{\sigma} \right) + p
  \Phi \left( \frac{x - u}{\sigma_c} \right)
\end{eqnarray*}
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of the standard normal
distribution.

As Stefan Hansen points out (many thanks), this is assuming independence of the underlying random variables.

Comment: Assuming that $I$ is independent of both $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: @StefanHansen Many thanks for improving the answer!

Comment: You're welcome :) +1

Comment: As usual it was more straightforward than I thought. Not to ask another question entirely, but do you guys know how I could get the probability density function from this? My thinking is that maybe you could distribute the Φ((x−u)/σ) through the (1-p). Then maybe the p's can be multiplied by the given normal distributions' probability density functions. Does that make sense? Thanks again in advance for any help!

Comment: @Spencevail Take derivatives with respect to $x$ to get the pdf.